# unable to create a record in process builder when criteria met

Tags: process-builder

I have 3 objects. Case, Issue and Problem

Case is parent of Issue and Issue is parent of CR. Having M-D relationships

I am trying to create process on Case object, when criteria met when creating case record then records in Issue and Problem should be created automatically.

I was able to create Issue record for the criteria.

To create an action for creating Problem record, I couldn't see {!Issue.Id} field to assign Id for creating record.

Any suggestion to achieve this??

[image]

Comment: Can you share screenshot of the same?

Comment: Added the screen shot, here I am looking for child object Issue__c, which is not displaying.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first:

> Process builder actions don't execute in a sequential flow. Therefore you can't rely which action will be executed first.

This is how you should approach it:

1. Create a process on Case to setup Issue
2. Create a process on Issue to setup child problems or CR's

   - Thanks

P.S. I am assuming after reading this, you will be able to find out the problem, if not I am happy to put more comments.

Comment: I understood you explanation, In short my requirement is to create a Issue and CR when criteria met on Case object. According to above explanation, we can create Issue record alone, but not CR. If i am not wrong.

How can i create CR record for the above created issue record automatically in PB? Let me know if i am confusing.

Comment: Just suggest a way, I will implement the solution

Comment: Why can't you create the CR? Is it dependent on Case?